# Low res images sent in iMessage are zoomed in

Tags: iphone, graphics, zoom

I send a 128x128 image via iMessage on my iPhone. I expect it to be quite small in the messages window, but it is zoomed in and pixelated for the recipient. It is actually already this large and pixelated before I have even sent it.

The annoying thing is that it was working as I expected a few weeks ago. I can’t recall exactly but it might have changed after an update (16.4.1a).

I copied the same image into the notes app and its small is expected there.

Comment: See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252217250?answerId=254210249022#254210249022

Comment: @Thinkr I found this thread too. Unfortunately they are talking about losing image quality, which is not my concern. The image I send is a few kB, so the display size of the image should be small. Instead it is large, which causes the pixelation.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too